# problem with trying to make the bot send a message to a channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make a verification command but when I try to send a message to an specific channel with `client.channels.cache.get('id')`  the code not work

It gives me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')

In this fragment:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1133739855042596955');
const response = channel.send({ 
  embeds: [ embedconfirmar ],
  components: [row]
});
```

My command file

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ActionRowBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('verificacion')
    .setDescription('Comando para verificarte')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('idroblox')
        .setDescription('nombre de usuario de roblox')
        .setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('idrp')
        .setDescription('Nombre RP')
        .setRequired(true)),

  async execute(interaction, message, client) {
    if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has('1138094416364589137')) {
      await interaction.reply({ content: 'Ya estas verificado', ephemeral: true });
    } else {
      const discorduser = interaction.user
      const robloxuser = interaction.options.getString('idroblox')
      const roleplayuser = interaction.options.getString('idrp')

      const embedconfirmar = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("¿Verificar miembro")
        .setDescription("Si los datos son correctos pulse aceptar.")
        .addFields(
          {
            name: "Discord",
            value: `${discorduser}`,
          },
          {
            name: "ROBLOX",
            value: `${robloxuser}`,
          },
          {
            name: "Nombre RP",
            value: `${roleplayuser}`,
          },
        )
        .setColor("#00b0f4")
        .setFooter({
          text: "Sistema de verificacion - Asturias RP",
          iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/1133734868598149121/ca3ff37bd87df6c771613abaeb49afc4.webp?size=96",
        })
        .setTimestamp();

      const memberr = interaction.member; // Guild member
      const interactionUser = interaction.user

      const embedvcancelada = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Error")
        .setDescription("Un moderador ha cancelado la verificacion")
        .setColor("#f50000")
        .setFooter({
          text: "Sistema de verificacion - Asturias RP",
        })
        .setTimestamp();

      const embedvcanceladamd = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Solicitud de verificacion rechazada")
        .setDescription("Un moderador ha cancelado la verificacion, vuelve a intentarlo rellenando bien los datos.Si se te sigue recazando la solicitud o crees que es un error contacta con un <@1133748311355035768> o <@1133748206463885333>")
        .setColor("#f50000")
        .setFooter({
          text: "Sistema de verificacion - Asturias RP",
        })
        .setTimestamp();

      const confirmar = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('confirmar')
        .setLabel('Confirmar')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success);

      const cancelar = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('cancelar')
        .setLabel('Cancelar')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);

      const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(cancelar, confirmar);

      const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1133739855042596955');
      const response = channel.send({ 
        embeds: [ embedconfirmar ],
        components: [row]
      });

      const embedexito = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Exito!")
        .setDescription("El usuario ha sido verificado")
        .setColor("#04f500")
        .setFooter({
          text: "Sistema de verificacion - Asturias RP",
        })
        .setTimestamp();

      const embedexitomd = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Verificacion Completada")
        .setDescription("Has sido verificado en Asturias RP, recuerda leer las <#1133737727465103421>")
        .setColor("#04f500")
        .setFooter({
          text: "Sistema de verificacion - Asturias RP",
        })
        .setTimestamp();

      try {
        const confirmation = await response.awaitMessageComponent();

        if (confirmation.customId === 'confirm') {
          await confirmation.update({ content: 'Verificado', components: [] });

          const guild = interaction.guild
          const role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Verificado'); // Find role named "Verificado" in cached roles
        
          await memberr.roles.add(role); // Add role to member

          memberr.setNickname(`${robloxuser}`)

          await interaction.reply({ embeds: [ embedexito ] });

          interactionUser.send({ embeds: [embedexitomd] })

          interactionUser.send({ embeds: [embedexito] })
        } else if (confirmation.customId === 'cancelar') {
          await confirmation.update({ content: 'Cancelado', components: [] });
          await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embedvcancelada] })

          interactionUser.send({embeds: [embedvcancelada]})
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('')
      }
    }
  },
};
```

index.js

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: 3276799 });

client.commands = new Collection();

const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}


// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
// We use 'c' for the event parameter to keep it separate from the already defined 'client'


// Log in to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

I tried changing `client` to `message.client` or `interaction.client` and searched in this website but nothing helped me

(I created my bot with [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.channels.cache.get('id')` maps all channels in all guilds bot is part of.

In your case as you are playing around with interaction, you could use: `const channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get('ID-HERE');`

Double check your channel ID you are using there is correct.